# "0x80070003" error getting while I custom web part in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, caml

"0x80070003" error getting while I retrieve Only document from the document library In scop="Recursive all" in caml Query and that caml Query data pass in the Webpart...but while I Insert that custom web part "0x80070003" error Occurd Give any suggestion

My CAML Query IS :

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
   <Query>
     <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
         <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
    </Eq> 
    </Where>
 </Query>
 </View>
```

Thank You..

Comment: Why ask the same question twice? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139355/0x80070003-error-while-web-part-add-and-web-part-contain-documents-from-the-doc Instead improve your first question if you have something to add/edit.

Comment: Sorry But I'm New In this thing...so.. @Dolgsthrasir

Comment: @Dolgsthrasir ..plese give Any Suggestion for Above If you have..

Comment: There is not enough Information to give you advice. Show some code besides the caml-query. Could be because of insufficient rights, but hard to tell without more information.

Answer (score 0):

I should say the problem is that your query is malformed. I will take a guess that you are using SSOM (C# in a .wsp)?

If so you should rewrite your query like this:

```
SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery{
    Query = @"<Where>
                 <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
                    <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value>
                 </Eq> 
              </Where>",
    ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'"
};
```